# Php to json does not pass all arrays (or json does not display all received values)

Tags: php, json

[image: Input form fields]

As see for the first and the third row all fields filled, for the second row some fields left blank.

Filled values with

```
$.post("__php_file.php", { 'number_of_input_row': number_of_input_row, 'date_day': date_day, 'date_month': date_month, 'date_year': date_year, 'currency': currency }, function(data, success) {

$('#currency_load1').html(data[0].FinalCurrencyRate);
$('#currency_load2').html(data[1].FinalCurrencyRate);
$('#currency_load3').html(data[2].FinalCurrencyRate);

}, "json");
```

send to php file, process and get such php array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [CurrencyAbbreviation] => AUD
            [DateOfCurrencyRate] => 2013-07-11
            [NumberOfInputRow] => 1
            [FinalCurrencyRate] => 0.506
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [CurrencyAbbreviation] => CAD
            [DateOfCurrencyRate] => 2013-07-25
            [NumberOfInputRow] => 3
            [FinalCurrencyRate] => 0.516
        )

)
```

json array is this

```
{
"0":{"CurrencyAbbreviation":"AUD","DateOfCurrencyRate":"2013-07-11","NumberOfInputRow":"1","FinalCurrencyRate":"0.506"},
"2":{"CurrencyAbbreviation":"CAD","DateOfCurrencyRate":"2013-07-25","NumberOfInputRow":"3","FinalCurrencyRate":"0.516"}
}
```

**So far all ok. But below is described problem**

Get back results and display here

```
<div id="currency_load1"></div>
<div id="currency_load2"></div>
<div id="currency_load3"></div>
```

However get displayed only `FinalCurrencyRate` for `AUD` or `[0] => Array`.

Question is: what need to correct to get displayed also `FinalCurrencyRate` from `[2] => Array`? As you see in php such array presents, but is not passed to json...

If fill all fields for the second row, then get displayed all three arrays.

**Update** Tried this

```
$('#currency_load1').html(data[0].FinalCurrencyRate);
$('#currency_load2').html("test to check");
$('#currency_load3').html(data[2].FinalCurrencyRate);
```

And all works. As understand within `jquery` need to create condition like `if FinalCurrencyRate is empty, then $('#currency_load2').html("0");`? But why such json/jquery behavior?

Comment: your php array is missing an element.

Comment: Try `data['2']`. FYI, numeric object keys are terrible

Comment: Tried `$('#currency_load3').html(data['2']);` see nothing...

Comment: @DevZer0 please, what element missing?

Comment: The row without a currency is not in your data structure